# SpriteKit Game: Moving Gameplay View

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skcameranode

[image]

I'm currently working on a **SpriteKit** game with a tile editor.  And I have a map like the following shown with a GameScene scene (.sks).  For now, it looks like the PacMan game.
As shown above, the game character stays at the center of the game screen.  Whenenver the user touches the screen, the game character will move to that touch point thanks to `touchesBegan`.  And the camera will follow the game character.  For now, I have the following.

```
enum GameStatus: Int {
    case waiting = 0
    case playing = 1
    case pausing = 2
    case gameOver = 3
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var background: SKTileMapNode! // background
    var player: SKNode! // player
    let cameraNode = SKCameraNode() // cameraNode

    // MARK: - DidMove
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        setupNodes()
        setupCamera()
    }

    // MARK: - Node set up
    func setupNodes() {
        // background //
        background = childNode(withName: "World") as! SKTileMapNode

        player = childNode(withName: "heroPlaying")
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 16)
        ...

        // game state //
        gameState = GameStatus.playing
    }

    // MARK: - Camera
    func setupCamera() {
        cameraNode.position = player.position
        addChild(cameraNode)
        camera = cameraNode
    }
    // MARK: - Camera

    // MARK: - Update
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if gameState == .playing {
            updateCamera()
        }
    }

    func updateCamera() {
        camera?.position = player.position
        //camera?.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x - 192, y: player.position.y - 192)
    }
}
```

Actuall, I only want to show the game screen partially so that I can display some statistics like the number of lives and coins.  So how can I move the game screen such that I can use the remaining area for showing stat numbers to the left and at the bottom?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a constraint to the camera to keep it at a distance of 0 from the player.  Then for your GUI, put all those nodes as childs of your camera.  That way, the gui will follow the camera no matter what you do to it (even scaling won't affect it).

***Constraint example:***

```
func setupCamera() {
  let distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(constantValue: 0), to: playerNode)
  cameraNode.constraints = [distanceConstraint]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  So how do I set a constraint to the camera?

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like a useful tip.  But I don't know how that magic 0 comes into play.  It seems that it's supposed to be an SKRange object.

Comment: It's the distance between the nodes.  You give it a distance and a target and you assign the constraint to the constraints array of the node you want to limit movement, in that case, the camera.  The 0 itself is a mistake that I'll fix right away, because you can actually specify a range, which could give some smooth camera effects.  but, to make it follow the player node perfectly, take a look at the edit.

Comment: It seems that what I need to use is SKConstraint.positionX(range: SKRange) and SKConstraint.positionY(range: SKRange) on SKCameraNode.  Additionally, you've said that I need to add nodes to the camera, which will cause my app to crash.

Comment: Well I litterally copied a piece of code from one of my projects, but I haven't touched it since I updated to Sierra 2 months ago, maybe they changed something.  I'll try and recompile it.  Adding nodes to the camera is to build your GUI.  Can I see your code?  What is the error you get when it crashes?

Comment: You decided to go with position vonstraints instead of distance constraints...  why is that?  Go read a bit about the SKConstraint class: it's supposed to be easy (at least I thought it was really easy) and you can combine constraints too.  It lets you do stuff like having te camera follow the player without getting of your scene's bounds etc.